# Installing ADO on Vista

Tags: ado, windows-vista

I need to develop a classic asp application on vista, and would like to know how to go about installing ADO on Vista Enterprise operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redistributable installer for the [MDAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937729.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. How can I verify if it has been installed?

Comment: A quick way to do it is to create a .udl file (just rename a blank text file to foo.udl). Then on that file, right click and do properties->provider and you should see the provider you intend to use (OLE DB Provier for SQL Server or whatever). You can also use the .udl file to build your connection string (bonus). :)

Comment: when my asp page gets to this line of code
   Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
it throws an error. http 500
I am thinking ado is not correctly installed.